# Need an HTTP gem for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, rubygems

I'm not pleased with Net::HTTP at all, and I'm looking for a lightweight gem that will either replace that library or at the very least hide it from me.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts/opinions on https://github.com/nahi/httpclient specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My vote goes to HTTParty. It's incredibly simple to use and can be as powerful as you choose. Here's a code sample:

```
HTTParty.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=New+York+NY&destinations=Los+Angeles+CA&mode=car&language=en&sensor=false")
```

Pretty simple stuff depending on what you're using it for.

Answer (score 2):

Try the RestClient gem:

https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client

Comment: I'll give this a try. at a quick glance it looks nice. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few out there.

Ruby toolbox has a http client list: http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients.html

Personally I usually use [HTTParty](http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)... or sometimes [Mechanize](http://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize), it's good for submitting forms

I would recommend checking the docs of each, to see which one suits your purpose best.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I looked at those two yesterday...I've forgotten my conclusions about HTTParty because it was so long ago :P I'll revisit that :) I thought Mechanize was kind of heavy for what I need. I'm basically just hitting various URLs to see if they are responsive and if the content is still safe (no f-bombs for the kids!)

Comment: Yeah Mechanize is a Beast, but can really come in handy when dealing with complex forms etc. sounds like you could probably go either rest-client or httparty. Just comes down to which flavour of DSL you like.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the `rest` gem, it was created and tested so we could find the best performing http gems by wrapping those gems and creating a standard interface to them. Turns out HTTParty and RestClient are very slow gems so I wouldn't recommend those, although you can always swap out the underlying gem in `rest` to see for yourself without having to change your code (other than initialization). `rest` gem by default will be much, much faster.

It's also very easy to use:

```
@rest = Rest::Client.new()
@rest.get(url, options...)
```

More info: https://github.com/iron-io/rest